# Is there a standard text mode tool to render heatmaps for arbitrary numeric matrix data?

Tags: git, data

For the curiosity's sake I created a script to visualize Git history week/hour-of-day basis timestamps in order to collect some stats. The following script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Declare the global heatmap hashmap
declare -A HEATMAP

# Composes a key in a form of a <WEEKDAY:1><HOUR:02>
function key {
    local WEEKDAY="$1"
    local HOUR="$2"
    echo -n "$WEEKDAY"
    if [[ "$HOUR" -lt 10 ]]; then
        echo -n '0'
    fi
    echo "$HOUR"
}

# Generate a sequence of weekdays (Mon-Sat,Sun)
function generate_weekdays {
    seq 1 6
    seq 0 0
}

# Generate a sequence of hours in day (00-23)
function generate_hours {
    seq 0 23
}

# Initialize and fill the heatmap with zeroes
for WEEKDAY in $(generate_weekdays); do
    for HOUR in $(generate_hours); do
        HEATMAP[$(key "$WEEKDAY" "$HOUR")]=0
    done
done

# Read the stats into the heatmap
MAX_PEAK=1
while read WEEKDAY_HOUR; do
    HEATMAP["$WEEKDAY_HOUR"]=$((${HEATMAP["$WEEKDAY_HOUR"]} + 1))
    if [[ ${HEATMAP["$WEEKDAY_HOUR"]} -gt "$MAX_PEAK" ]]; then
        MAX_PEAK=${HEATMAP["$WEEKDAY_HOUR"]}
    fi
done < <(git rev-list --date=format:'%w%H' --pretty='format:%ad' $@ | awk 'NR % 2 == 0')

# Render the heatmap
RATIO=0
for WEEKDAY in $(generate_weekdays); do
    for HOUR in $(generate_hours); do
        RATIO=$((100 * ${HEATMAP[$(key "$WEEKDAY" "$HOUR")]} / $MAX_PEAK))
        if [[ "$RATIO" -eq 0 ]]; then echo -ne '\e[38;5;236m'
        elif [[ "$RATIO" -lt 10 ]]; then echo -ne '\e[38;5;107m'
        elif [[ "$RATIO" -lt 20 ]]; then echo -ne '\e[38;5;22m'
        elif [[ "$RATIO" -lt 30 ]]; then echo -ne '\e[38;5;28m'
        elif [[ "$RATIO" -lt 40 ]]; then echo -ne '\e[38;5;70m'
        elif [[ "$RATIO" -lt 50 ]]; then echo -ne '\e[38;5;190m'
        elif [[ "$RATIO" -lt 60 ]]; then echo -ne '\e[38;5;226m'
        elif [[ "$RATIO" -lt 70 ]]; then echo -ne '\e[38;5;220m'
        elif [[ "$RATIO" -lt 80 ]]; then echo -ne '\e[38;5;214m'
        elif [[ "$RATIO" -lt 90 ]]; then echo -ne '\e[38;5;208m'
        elif [[ "$RATIO" -lt 100 ]]; then echo -ne '\e[38;5;160m'
        elif [[ "$RATIO" -eq 100 ]]; then echo -ne '\e[38;5;196m'; fi
        echo -n '*'
        echo -ne '\e[0m'
    done
    echo
done
```

invoked as `./git-heatmap --all` produces a sample output as depicted below (not at a Linux machine currently, running on Windows/MinGW with the Fixedsys font, I prefer squares, `\u2BC0`, to asterisks, but Fixedsys cannot render the squares that I find much nicer):

[image: ./git-heatmap --all example output]

Since the script does three jobs:

- consumes Git weekday/hour-of-day timestamps output,
- calculates the stats,
- and renders the heatmap

... I'm wondering is there something like a standard tool that calculates/renders something similar to the heatmap above? My script processes the following sample data supplied by Git:

```
100
101
420
517
...
```

where the first digit designates a weekday, and the second and the third digits designate a day hour. Thanks.